# Cycle elements in an array whilst respecting blank elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a staff/shift assignment tool where each week staff will be assigned to tasks. The next week I want to be able to shift all the staff down one task on the list. The last staff member cycles back to the top of the list.

The issue is I want to respect the blank cells in the array, i.e. they should stay where they are and the staff cycle around them.

Like so:

[image]

I've got it working, but I don't think my code is the greatest so looking for better options. I.e. more readable and maintainable.

Here's a working example:

```
let assignedStaff = [
  {periodId: 1, staffName: "Jimbo"},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: ""},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: "Lucy"},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: ""},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: "Claire"}];

let newPeriod = [];

//Get only the populated staff
populated = assignedStaff.filter(element => element.staffName !== "");

//Move the last staff member to the front
populated.unshift(populated.pop());

for(let i = 0, assigned = 0; i < assignedStaff.length; i++){
  
  if(assignedStaff[i].staffName !== ""){
    
    newPeriod.push(populated[assigned]);
    assigned++
    
  }
  else
    {
      newPeriod.push(assignedStaff[i])
    }
  
}

console.log(newPeriod);
```

and here's a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wucodadiki/edit?js,console). The results are a bit more readable than the run snippet tool.

Answer (score 1):

A probably cleaner solution would be removing the empty elements initially, but keeping their indexes. Then you execute the rotate right (`populated.unshift(populated.pop());`), and finally you insert the empty elements at the original indexes:

```js
let assignedStaff = [
  {periodId: 1, staffName: "Jimbo"},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: ""},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: "Lucy"},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: ""},
  {periodId: 1, staffName: "Claire"}];

// [1, 3]
let emptyIndexes = assignedStaff.map((x, i) => x.staffName === "" ? i : null).filter(i => i !== null)
let cleanedStaff = assignedStaff.filter(x => x.staffName !== "")
cleanedStaff.unshift(cleanedStaff.pop())

for (const i of emptyIndexes)
    cleanedStaff.splice(i, 0, assignedStaff[i])
  
console.log(cleanedStaff)
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about doing it this way. And it's good the way you've done it too, because the blank elements have all sorts of other stuff assigned to them that I haven't added in my example code, like ids etc.